# Using Racket ISL to define function using list abstractions

Tags: racket, abstraction

I am trying to create a function that accepts a number and then produces text they can temporarily copy into their paper as a space saver. Here are a few examples below:

```
(define
  CITATION-SPACE-2
  (string-append
   "[1] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information\n"
   "[2] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information"))

(define
  CITATION-SPACE-3
  (string-append
   "[1] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information\n"
   "[2] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information\n"
   "[3] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information"))

(check-expect (citation-space 2) CITATION-SPACE-2)
(check-expect (citation-space 3) CITATION-SPACE-3)
```

I have been able to define the function using cond and string-append but can't figure out how to have a \n between each line of the result (though not after the last line). Also, I am unsure how to define and simplify the function using the foldr list abstraction.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
(define (citation-space num)
  (local [; data-string : Nat -> String
          ; produces a space saver
          ; for a supplied number
          (define (data-string num)
            (foldl (λ (s1 s2)
                     (string-append s2 "\n" s1))
                   (string-append
                    "[" (number->string num) "]"
                    " author information")
                   (list "title information"
                         "venue information"
                         "year & page information")))]
    (cond
      [(zero? num) ""]
      [(= num 1) (data-string 1)]
      [else (string-append
             (citation-space (sub1 num))
             "\n"
             (data-string num))])))
```

Comment: It seems that you have some errors in examples- `CITATION-SPACE-2` is equal to `CITATION-SPACE-3` and there's no `CITATION-SPACE-5`.

Comment: Just fixed it in an edit. Thank you. Hopefully this improved version helps. @MartinPůda

Comment: Do you really have to use `foldr` or you can also use `foldl`? And is this exercise from some site/book available online?

Comment: foldr or foldl both work for this function. This is not from a site/book but rather custom exercises I am doing for practice given by my professor.@MartinPůda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't have to do this exercise in ISL, you could use [`string-join`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-join%29%29) provided by `racket/string`.

If you didn't have to use `foldl` or `foldr`, you could write something like this:

```
(define (my-join strs sep)
  (cond ((null? strs) "")
        ((= (length strs) 1) (first strs))
        (else (string-append (first strs)
                             sep
                             (my-join (rest strs) sep)))))
```

But I think it's possible to solve this problem also with pair of `foldl`. Used language is Intermediate Student with Lambda:

```
(define
  CITATION-SPACE-2
  (string-append
   "[1] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information\n"
   "[2] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information"))

(define
  CITATION-SPACE-3
  (string-append
   "[1] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information\n"
   "[2] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information\n"
   "[3] author information\n"
   "title information\n"
   "venue information\n"
   "year & page information"))

(define (data-string number)
  (foldl (lambda (s result)
           (string-append result "\n" s))
         (format "[~a] author information" number)
         (list "title information"
               "venue information"
               "year & page information")))

(define (citation-space number)
  (if (zero? number) ""
      (let ((strs (map data-string (range 1 (add1 number) 1))))
        (foldl (lambda (s result) (string-append result "\n" s))
               (first strs)
               (rest strs)))))

(check-expect (citation-space 2) CITATION-SPACE-2)
(check-expect (citation-space 3) CITATION-SPACE-3)
```

**EDIT:** Solution with one `foldl`:

```
(define (data-string number)
  (foldl (lambda (s result)
           (string-append result "\n" s))
         (format "[~a] author information" number)
         (list "title information"
               "venue information"
               "year & page information")))

(define (citation-space num)
  (cond
    [(zero? num) ""]
    [(= num 1) (data-string 1)]
    [else (string-append
           (citation-space (sub1 num))
           "\n"
           (data-string num))]))
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this using one foldl? I am trying to keep the syntax similar to mine too.

Comment: This is much better but I was hoping you could avoid that second cond where it states "(= num 1) (data-string 1)"?

Comment: In my edit above, I have a simplified version of your solution that follows the syntax I am looking for.